# In MySQL, can you insert multiple values to a row in a table

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and I am very new to the concepts.
In one of my assignments, we are inserting values to our table.

In the table, there are several columns and the rows have multiple values in it.

outcome requested:

[image: outcome requested]

Does this create a constraint?

I feel like this is a trick question from my instructor.
Thank you in advance :)

My current draft:

```
Insert into sale (saleid, employeeid, personid, saledate)
Values (1,2,7,'2020-09-22'),
       (2,3,1,'2020-09-22'),
       (3,3,9,'2020-09-22');

Insert into saledetail (saleid, saledetailid, inventoryid, quantity)
Values (1,1,23456,3),
       (1,1,23457,1),
       (1,1,23460,2),
       (2,2,23461,2),
       (3,3,23462,1),
       (3,3,23461,0.5),
       (3,3,23457,1);
```

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a comma-separated list in the result.

Comment: You need to join with the tables that have the member and employee names, product descriptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, in you database, you should use two tables linked "one-to-many", where the second one contains all necessary "multiple values", one per row, and unique ID of a row in the first table.

Also, to ensure data consistency, you may want to use foreign key constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html